# Appveyor deploy to Azure cloud service with Web.config transform

Tags: web.config-transform, appveyor

How can I configure which Web.config to use in deployment to Azure Cloud Services?

I have two files (Web.config and Web.Staging.config) how can I configure to transform Web.config using Web.Staging.config?

I will change the question: in AppVeyor build and deploy process there is a command linke that:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "C:\projects\xxxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxx.AzureCloudService\xxxxxxxxxxx.AzureCloudService.ccproj" /p:Configuration="**Release**" /p:Platform="AnyCPU" /verbosity:minimal /logger:"C:\Program Files\AppVeyor\BuildAgent\Appveyor.MSBuildLogger.dll" /t:Publish /p:PublishDir=C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\th712xjsl2\
```

In that command, there is a parameter called Configuration that has a fixed "Release".
How can I change this parameter to another configuration?
Is there a way in AppVeyor settings or in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Web.config transformation is run at the time Azure cloud service package creation and is controlled by solution *configuration*.

However, you cannot choose between different web.configs during the deployment as cloud service package already contains transformed web.config.

This blog post describes a nice approach of how you can change Azure cloud service configs at the time of deployment: https://blogs.endjin.com/2015/03/using-a-different-new-relic-application-name-per-environment-with-azure-cloud-services/